# ddrescue: How to restart from pass 1?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

I've been trying to recover data from a 500GB WD Scorpio Blue drive I found recently that was from an old Acer laptop. I ran it for about a day before the read rate had slowed down to about 50KB/S and it had only rescued about 60GB. I then added -a100000 to the command (skip ahead if read rate falls below 100KB/S) and it rescued about 300GB in only a few hours! However, when it got to pass 3 (rescue what was skipped in pass 1 & 2) the speed had dropped to only ~20KB/S and would take about 3 months to finish. So I would like to restart from pass one, this time with -a50000 (-a is ignored in pass 3).

I came across [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517229/ddrescue-how-to-re-run-first-pass-dont-do-reverse-yet), however in their case they were still on pass 2, where -a isn't ignored.

Comment: Sounds like WD slow response bug. https://mod2patch.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an option for that:

```
       -A, --try-again
              mark non-trimmed, non-scraped as non-tried

       -M, --retrim
              mark all failed blocks as non-trimmed
```

(Both options can be specified, if you want to retry "failed" blocks from stage 1.)

Failing that, manually (or using `ddrescuelog -a`) edit the log file to mark the ranges with `?` if they are currently marked with anything else than `+`. See `info "(ddrescue)Mapfile structure"` for the format details.